# double summation derivation problem

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, summation, partial-derivative, least-squares

I am having hard time understanding the concept of double summation derivation. 
I have this model 
$${L}=\sum_{i=1}^a\sum_{j=1}^n (y_{ij}-\mu-\tau_i)^2$$
which is the fixed effects model for one way ANOVA. Now, to estimate the parameters $\mu$ and $\tau_i$ I need to used the least squares method and using the partial derivatives I would be able to get them. The book says that $$\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\mu}}=-2\sum_{i=1}^a\sum_{j=1}^n (y_{ij}-\hat\mu-\hat\tau_i)=0$$ which I understand. 
What I don't understand is that the other derivative
$$\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\tau}}=-2\sum_{j=1}^n(y_{ij}+\hat\mu-\hat\tau_i)=0$$

How does the sign differ between these two derivatives? Also, where did the sigma operator of i go? can you derive the 2nd derivative in simple steps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You missed the fact that what you have to write is the derivative with respect to $\tau_i$ $$\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\tau_{\color{red}{i}}}}=-2\sum_{j=1}^n(y_{ij}+\hat\mu-\hat\tau_i)$$ About the sign, don't care since you will set the derivatives equal to $0$.

Comment: can you walk me throught how to differniate with respect to a continuous parameter?

Comment: @Has. Write the equations for $n=2$. This is really a classical problem (you seem to be afraid by the double summation).

Comment: I tried to do it for n=2 and a=2 but I still couldn't crack it